# ElasticSearch : how to rank on skill rating in full text search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have quite a simple case but can't find the good way to solve it:

I have `People`, their `Skills` are rated. They also have other information attached (eg: city). All of this is in my ElasticSearch index.

Example:

John
Paris
Python: 7/10

Boris
Paris
Python: 3/10

Mike
Frankfurt
Python: 7/10

I would like to perform a **text search only** to find people.

- If I type "Python", the better rated someone is, the higher it should be
- If I type "Python Paris", it should get all people in Paris sorted by Python rating

Here is an example of people document in ES index:

```
    {
  "_index": "senso",
  "_type": "talent",
  "_id": "12469",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "id": 12469,
    "nickname": "Roger",
    "first_name": "Moore",
    "last_name": "Bond",
    "companyName": null,
    "email": "example@example.org",
    "city": "Marseille",
    "region": "Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur",
    "internalGlobalRating": 5,
    "declaredDailyPrice": 650,
    "declaredAnnualSalaryTarget": null,
    "boughtDailyPrice": null,
    "soldDailyPrice": null,
    "skillsRatings": [
      {
        "skillName": "Direction Artistique Web",
        "skillId": 1298,
        "rating": 9
      },
      {
        "skillName": "UX Design",
        "skillId": 1295,
        "rating": 9
      },
      {
        "skillName": "Identité Visuelle",
        "skillId": 1319,
        "rating": 8
      },
      {
        "skillName": "Illustrator",
        "skillId": 1425,
        "rating": 9
      },
      {
        "skillName": "Photoshop",
        "skillId": 1427,
        "rating": 9
      },
      {
        "skillName": "InDesign",
        "skillId": 1426,
        "rating": 9
      }
    ],
    "expertises": [
      {
        "name": "Direction Artistique Web",
        "id": 1298
      },
      {
        "name": "UX Design",
        "id": 1295
      },
      {
        "name": "Identité Visuelle",
        "id": 1319
      }
    ],
    "missionTypes": [
      {
        "name": "Freelance sur place",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Freelance en télétravail",
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "Forfait",
        "id": 4
      }
    ],
    "tools": [
      {
        "name": "Illustrator",
        "id": 1425
      },
      {
        "name": "Photoshop",
        "id": 1427
      },
      {
        "name": "InDesign",
        "id": 1426
      }
    ],
    "themes": [],
    "medias": [],
    "organizationType": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Studio"
    },
    "source": {
      "id": 2
    },
    "spokenLanguages": [
      {
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 3
      }
    ],
    "mainLanguage": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Français"
    }
    "created": "2011-10-05T20:17:52+02:00",
    "updated": "2017-07-03T15:59:11+02:00",
    "applicationDate": "2011-10-05T20:17:52+02:00",
    "portfolio": {
      "id": 95,
      "visible": true,
      "submissionTime": "2017-01-13T18:20:31+01:00",
      "isDisplayed": 1,
      "isPublic": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder which approach I should choose : tweak at index time or custom queries, or both ?

Any clue on how to tackle this problem would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your actual JSON documents for the 3 examples above

Comment: I have added an example of a "talent" document in the index. Ratings are in ```skillsRatings``` and the city in ```city```